# Unable to decrypt the encrypted value in crypto-js using crypto-js in ionic3 app

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ionic3, cryptojs

-I have successfully carried out the encryption part of the username and -- 
 -password value using crypto-js in the ionic v3 app for capturing it into -firebase-analytics.

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

class Model {
    param1: string;
    value:any;
    myPassword = "my message 123";


function decrypt(this.someuservalue:any,this.somemailid:any){
const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(this.someuservalue,
 myPassword).toString();
}

}
```

-have obtained encrypted values in the firebase database as well.

-But now to decrypt it in another independent javascript file I'm not able to do it.
-Here is how I'm trying to decrypt it

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipher, value);
var plaintext = = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

-But I'm unable to do so,
-Any help can be greatly appreciated.

-Thanks,

-I've tried

```
var cipher = "encrypted value from the above implemented encryption"
password = "my message 123";

var rawData = atob(cipher);
    var iv = btoa(rawData.substring(0,16));
    var crypttext = btoa(rawData.substring(16));
    var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
 {
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(crypttext),
    salt: ""
  },
  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(password),
  { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv) }
);
```

-and

```
var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(cipher)
}, password, {format: CryptoJS.format.Utf8 });
var plaintext = bytes.toString();
```

-both didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Sodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.js) (libsodium.js).

Sodium is a modern, easy-to-use software library for encryption, decryption, signatures, password hashing and more.

It is a portable, cross-compilable, installable, packageable fork of NaCl, with a compatible API, and an extended API to improve usability even further.

Its goal is to provide all of the core operations needed to build higher-level cryptographic tools.

Sodium is cross-platforms and cross-languages. It runs on a variety of compilers and operating systems, including Windows (with MinGW or Visual Studio, x86 and x86_64), iOS and Android. Javascript and WebAssembly versions are also available and are fully supported. Bindings for all common programming languages are available and well-supported.

The design choices emphasize security and ease of use. But despite the emphasis on high security, primitives are faster across-the-board than most implementations.

Version 1.0.17 was released on January 7, 2019.

Ref:

- Sodium [GitBook](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/installation)
- [List of awesome JavaScript Crypto Libraries](https://github.com/gabrielizalo/Awesome-JavaScript-Crypto-Libraries)
- [JavaScript Crypto Libraries](https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441)